# room rxjava calls onNext several times even without database change

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I have a project that uses Room with RXJava because I need to hear the changes in the bank and reflect this in real time on screen.

When I open the screen that needs this data it subscribes to this query and the data arrives on the screen correctly but when placing a brackpoint and debugging I can see that onNext is called many times without stopping even without database changes.

Does anyone know if this behavior can be changed, would like onNext to be called only when there are changes in the database

```
@Dao
public abstract class CarDao {   
    @Query("SELECT * FROM cars ")
    public abstract Observable<List<Car>> fetchCars();
}
```

View

```
public MyActivity extends Activity {
    ........
    public void fetchCars(){
       carDAO.fetchCars()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<List<Car>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Car> Cars) {
                       **Log.d("app", "MyActivity - carDAO.getCar - onNext ")**
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {}
                });    
        }
}
```

Comment: where do you call `fetchCars()` method?

Comment: Whenever you subscribe for the first time, carDAO.fetchCars() will emit all the data present in database according to query and after that, it will listen for changes.

Comment: Even if done right (those multiple calls are likely some non room related bug), I doubt you will be able to receive changes without using LiveData.